# How to use Angular in Synology DS218J

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, synology

I uses Synology NAS DS218J

I installed Node.js v8, "Easy bootstrap Installer", perl and iPKGui.
I installed package gcc, make, libc-dev through ipkg.
I installed angular cli `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli` and then configure alias 'ng'

when I try to make a new Angular project, error pops
`ng new testAngular`

I can't find how to solve this problem.
I think libintl.h is included in libc-dev package, even though I installed it, doesn't work.

please help me.

below is error logs

```
$ ng new testAngular
...
...
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/volume1/homes/khackskjs/testA/node_modules/node-sass/build'
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.4"' -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/include/node -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/src -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/deps/openssl/config -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/deps/uv/include -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/deps/zlib -I/var/services/homes/khackskjs/.node-gyp/8.9.4/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++0x -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
In file included from /volume1/@optware/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:2008:0,
                 from /volume1/@optware/include/c++/7.2.0/locale:41,
                 from /volume1/@optware/include/c++/7.2.0/iomanip:43,
                 from ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp:11:
/volume1/@optware/include/c++/7.2.0/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/bits/messages_members.h:36:10: fatal error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libintl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
src/libsass.target.mk:148: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/volume1/homes/khackskjs/testA/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/volume1/homes/khackskjs/testA/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.105
gyp ERR! command "/volume1/@appstore/Node.js_v8/usr/local/bin/node" "/volume1/homes/khackskjs/testA/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /volume1/homes/khackskjs/testA/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: Not related to Angular. You can use Angular without Angular CLI.

Comment: @estus Thank you for your replying. It's not related Angular, but also gyp. I think I have to resolve the problem 'not found libintl.h'. when I install some module such as node-sass, the same problem happens. do you have any idea?

Comment: I have no idea, seems like this is specific to platform and compiler. The question is focused on Node while this may be specific to OS and be https://unix.stackexchange.com/ question. I'm not sure what's your case, are you trying to use NAS as a tool for development? Because you don't need angular-cli just to run a website. Any way, if you don't need sass there, you don't need it. Eject Angular CLI app and remove the support for sass.

Answer (score 4):

If some one else needs to install angular 6 or a major version in a synology NAS with DSM >= 6.2 you can use the below commands for install it:

```
1. Install node (v8 for this case) from the package manager.
```

In the terminal run the below commands

```
npm install npm@latest -g

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1

npm install typescript@2.7.8
```

if the command ng was not found you can try execute this:

get the angular-cli path

```
sudo find / -type d -name @angular
```

Set the result of the above command in the alias

```
alias ng=“/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng”
```

Enjoy